# phptal: how do I repeatedly add attributes?

Tags: php, attributes, repeat, template-tal, phptal

I got a phptal template question, I have an associative array which contains HTML attribute information, e.g.

```
attrs['href'] = 'www.google.com';
attrs['id'] = 'the_link';
...
```

Is there a way to use the "repeat" to loop through my array and generate the attributes dynamically? (I know how to do it statically)

so I can have

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="the_link">abc</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, TAL doesn't have construct for this. You'll need fixed attributes:

```
tal:attributes="href attrs/href | nothing; id attrs/id | nothing"
```

or generate the tag yourself:

```
 ${structure php:generate_tag(attrs)}
```

Comment: ${structure php:generate_tag(attrs)}
where should I put this line into? I have tried this: <input type="text" ${structure php:render_input_attributes(field)}></input> and it failed

Comment: Put it outside tag. It's supposed to output complete tag in an oldschool PHP way.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is right -- you can't "loop through attributes"

And I know this is an old thread -- but couldn't you just use `tal:attributes` -- it seems like it's exactly intended for this automatically. (See http://phptal.org/manual/en/#tal-attributes)

```
<a tal:attributes="attrs">abc</a>
```